# jQuery Selectable to not insert classes into all childs

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

Thanks for the help. Code below is part of a table. I have Selectable setup on the table row, so it allows td to be selectable and that works.. As you notice, jQuery Selectable adds a class to EVERYTHING... I don't want that because I want to be able to unselect a selected td. Depending on were I click on the TD. I might just unselect the td, but the child objects are still highlighted

```js
$("tr.schedule__row").bind("mousedown", function(e) {
  e.metaKey = true;
}).selectable({

});
```

```css
/*Stop from selecting the first column*/

.scheduleTableActual tbody td:first-child {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.ui-selected {
  background: #F39814 !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table id="scheduleTable" class="scheduleTableActual">

  <thead class="scheduleHeader">
    <tr class="scheduleHeader__row">
      <th class="scheduleHeader__item schedule__session">
        <div class="scheduleHeader__item--wrap">Sessions</div>
      </th>
      <th class="scheduleHeader__item schedule__session">
        <div class="scheduleHeader__item--wrap">Mon 06/25</div>
      </th>
      <th class="scheduleHeader__item schedule__session">
        <div class="scheduleHeader__item--wrap">Tue 06/26</div>
      </th>
      <th class="scheduleHeader__item schedule__session">
        <div class="scheduleHeader__item--wrap">Wed 06/27</div>
      </th>
      <th class="scheduleHeader__item schedule__session">
        <div class="scheduleHeader__item--wrap">Thu 06/28</div>
      </th>
      <th class="scheduleHeader__item schedule__session">
        <div class="scheduleHeader__item--wrap">Fri 06/29</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="schedule__body">
    <tr class="schedule__row" id="172">
      <td class="schedule__cell schedule__session">
        <div class="schedule__cell--wrap"><span class="schedule__session--title">Session 1</span><span class="schedule__session--time">8:00 AM - 11:00 AM</span></div>
      </td>
      <td class="schedule__cell">
        <div data-sessionid="172" data-instancedate="06/25/2018" class="schedule__cell--wrap"><input data-testid="46181" data-sessionid="172" data-instanceid="571" data-instancedate="06/25/2018" type="hidden"><span>Algebra I</span><br><input data-testid="46184" data-sessionid="172" data-instanceid="572" data-instancedate="06/25/2018" type="hidden"><span>Biology</span><br>
          <input
            data-testid="46185" data-sessionid="172" data-instanceid="573" data-instancedate="06/25/2018" type="hidden"><span>U.S. History</span><br></div>
      </td>
      <td class="schedule__cell">
        <div data-sessionid="172" data-instancedate="06/26/2018" class="schedule__cell--wrap"><input data-testid="46182" data-sessionid="172" data-instanceid="306" data-instancedate="06/26/2018" type="hidden"><span>English I</span><br><input data-testid="46183" data-sessionid="172" data-instanceid="307" data-instancedate="06/26/2018" type="hidden"><span>English II </span><br></div>
      </td>
      <td class="schedule__cell">
        <div data-sessionid="172" data-instancedate="06/27/2018" class="schedule__cell--wrap"><input data-testid="46181" data-sessionid="172" data-instanceid="338" data-instancedate="06/27/2018" type="hidden"><span>Algebra I</span><br><input data-testid="46184" data-sessionid="172" data-instanceid="339" data-instancedate="06/27/2018" type="hidden"><span>Biology</span><br>
          <input
            data-testid="46185" data-sessionid="172" data-instanceid="340" data-instancedate="06/27/2018" type="hidden"><span>U.S. History</span><br></div>
      </td>
      <td class="schedule__cell">
        <div data-sessionid="172" data-instancedate="06/28/2018" class="schedule__cell--wrap"><input data-testid="46182" data-sessionid="172" data-instanceid="308" data-instancedate="06/28/2018" type="hidden"><span>English I</span><br><input data-testid="46183" data-sessionid="172" data-instanceid="309" data-instancedate="06/28/2018" type="hidden"><span>English II </span><br></div>
      </td>
      <td class="schedule__cell">
        <div data-sessionid="172" data-instancedate="06/29/2018" class="schedule__cell--wrap"><input data-testid="46185" data-sessionid="172" data-instanceid="576" data-instancedate="06/29/2018" type="hidden"><span>U.S. History</span><br></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="schedule__row" id="173">
      <td class="schedule__cell schedule__session">
        <div class="schedule__cell--wrap"><span class="schedule__session--title">Session 2</span><span class="schedule__session--time">12:00 PM - 3:00 PM</span></div>
      </td>
      <td class="schedule__cell">
        <div data-sessionid="173" data-instancedate="06/25/2018" class="schedule__cell--wrap"><input data-testid="46182" data-sessionid="173" data-instanceid="310" data-instancedate="06/25/2018" type="hidden"><span>English I</span><br><input data-testid="46183" data-sessionid="173" data-instanceid="311" data-instancedate="06/25/2018" type="hidden"><span>English II </span><br></div>
      </td>
      <td class="schedule__cell">
        <div data-sessionid="173" data-instancedate="06/26/2018" class="schedule__cell--wrap"><input data-testid="46181" data-sessionid="173" data-instanceid="341" data-instancedate="06/26/2018" type="hidden"><span>Algebra I</span><br><input data-testid="46184" data-sessionid="173" data-instanceid="342" data-instancedate="06/26/2018" type="hidden"><span>Biology</span><br>
          <input
            data-testid="46185" data-sessionid="173" data-instanceid="343" data-instancedate="06/26/2018" type="hidden"><span>U.S. History</span><br></div>
      </td>
      <td class="schedule__cell">
        <div data-sessionid="173" data-instancedate="06/27/2018" class="schedule__cell--wrap"><input data-testid="46182" data-sessionid="173" data-instanceid="312" data-instancedate="06/27/2018" type="hidden"><span>English I</span><br><input data-testid="46183" data-sessionid="173" data-instanceid="313" data-instancedate="06/27/2018" type="hidden"><span>English II </span><br></div>
      </td>
      <td class="schedule__cell">
        <div data-sessionid="173" data-instancedate="06/28/2018" class="schedule__cell--wrap"><input data-testid="46181" data-sessionid="173" data-instanceid="344" data-instancedate="06/28/2018" type="hidden"><span>Algebra I</span><br><input data-testid="46184" data-sessionid="173" data-instanceid="345" data-instancedate="06/28/2018" type="hidden"><span>Biology</span><br>
          <input
            data-testid="46185" data-sessionid="173" data-instanceid="346" data-instancedate="06/28/2018" type="hidden"><span>U.S. History</span><br></div>
      </td>
      <td class="schedule__cell">
        <div data-sessionid="173" data-instancedate="06/29/2018" class="schedule__cell--wrap"><svg data-instancedate="06/29/2018" class="schedule__cell--icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path fill="currentColor" d="M16 32C7.163 32 0 24.837 0 16S7.163 0 16 0s16 7.163 16 16-7.163 16-16 16zm2-18V8a2 2 0 1 0-4 0v6H8a2 2 0 1 0 0 4h6v6a2 2 0 1 0 4 0v-6h6a2 2 0 1 0 0-4h-6z"></path></svg></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://codepen.io/54696d20/pen/EGPjag

You can see what I mean on the codepen. Click, drag (like you are trying to highlight everything), and then click each one. I'll noticed that words stay highlighted. This causes an issue with Selectable's unselected method

Comment: @Pete Cool. I updated it and it's working (to show the example) / not working (what I need it to do) lol

Comment: nice, I gave you an upvote to cancel out the other downvote now it's been fixed

Comment: @Pete Thanks! I didn't even know it was there. I'll make sure to use it next time

Answer (score 0):

I always do this, but I have the answer. I added some code in the selected method

```js
$("tr.schedule__row").bind("mousedown", function(e) {
  e.metaKey = true;
}).selectable({
   selected: function (event, ui) {
        $('div.schedule__cell--wrap').removeClass("ui-selected");
        $('div.schedule__cell--wrap > span.ui-selectee').removeClass("ui-selected");
        $('div.schedule__cell--wrap > br').removeClass("ui-selected");
    },
});
```

```css
/*Stop from selecting the first column*/

.scheduleTableActual tbody td:first-child {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.ui-selected {
  background: #F39814 !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table id="scheduleTable" class="scheduleTableActual">

  <thead class="scheduleHeader">
    <tr class="scheduleHeader__row">
      <th class="scheduleHeader__item schedule__session">
        <div class="scheduleHeader__item--wrap">Sessions</div>
      </th>
      <th class="scheduleHeader__item schedule__session">
        <div class="scheduleHeader__item--wrap">Mon 06/25</div>
      </th>
      <th class="scheduleHeader__item schedule__session">
        <div class="scheduleHeader__item--wrap">Tue 06/26</div>
      </th>
      <th class="scheduleHeader__item schedule__session">
        <div class="scheduleHeader__item--wrap">Wed 06/27</div>
      </th>
      <th class="scheduleHeader__item schedule__session">
        <div class="scheduleHeader__item--wrap">Thu 06/28</div>
      </th>
      <th class="scheduleHeader__item schedule__session">
        <div class="scheduleHeader__item--wrap">Fri 06/29</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="schedule__body">
    <tr class="schedule__row" id="172">
      <td class="schedule__cell schedule__session">
        <div class="schedule__cell--wrap"><span class="schedule__session--title">Session 1</span><span class="schedule__session--time">8:00 AM - 11:00 AM</span></div>
      </td>
      <td class="schedule__cell">
        <div data-sessionid="172" data-instancedate="06/25/2018" class="schedule__cell--wrap"><input data-testid="46181" data-sessionid="172" data-instanceid="571" data-instancedate="06/25/2018" type="hidden"><span>Algebra I</span><br><input data-testid="46184" data-sessionid="172" data-instanceid="572" data-instancedate="06/25/2018" type="hidden"><span>Biology</span><br>
          <input
            data-testid="46185" data-sessionid="172" data-instanceid="573" data-instancedate="06/25/2018" type="hidden"><span>U.S. History</span><br></div>
      </td>
      <td class="schedule__cell">
        <div data-sessionid="172" data-instancedate="06/26/2018" class="schedule__cell--wrap"><input data-testid="46182" data-sessionid="172" data-instanceid="306" data-instancedate="06/26/2018" type="hidden"><span>English I</span><br><input data-testid="46183" data-sessionid="172" data-instanceid="307" data-instancedate="06/26/2018" type="hidden"><span>English II </span><br></div>
      </td>
      <td class="schedule__cell">
        <div data-sessionid="172" data-instancedate="06/27/2018" class="schedule__cell--wrap"><input data-testid="46181" data-sessionid="172" data-instanceid="338" data-instancedate="06/27/2018" type="hidden"><span>Algebra I</span><br><input data-testid="46184" data-sessionid="172" data-instanceid="339" data-instancedate="06/27/2018" type="hidden"><span>Biology</span><br>
          <input
            data-testid="46185" data-sessionid="172" data-instanceid="340" data-instancedate="06/27/2018" type="hidden"><span>U.S. History</span><br></div>
      </td>
      <td class="schedule__cell">
        <div data-sessionid="172" data-instancedate="06/28/2018" class="schedule__cell--wrap"><input data-testid="46182" data-sessionid="172" data-instanceid="308" data-instancedate="06/28/2018" type="hidden"><span>English I</span><br><input data-testid="46183" data-sessionid="172" data-instanceid="309" data-instancedate="06/28/2018" type="hidden"><span>English II </span><br></div>
      </td>
      <td class="schedule__cell">
        <div data-sessionid="172" data-instancedate="06/29/2018" class="schedule__cell--wrap"><input data-testid="46185" data-sessionid="172" data-instanceid="576" data-instancedate="06/29/2018" type="hidden"><span>U.S. History</span><br></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="schedule__row" id="173">
      <td class="schedule__cell schedule__session">
        <div class="schedule__cell--wrap"><span class="schedule__session--title">Session 2</span><span class="schedule__session--time">12:00 PM - 3:00 PM</span></div>
      </td>
      <td class="schedule__cell">
        <div data-sessionid="173" data-instancedate="06/25/2018" class="schedule__cell--wrap"><input data-testid="46182" data-sessionid="173" data-instanceid="310" data-instancedate="06/25/2018" type="hidden"><span>English I</span><br><input data-testid="46183" data-sessionid="173" data-instanceid="311" data-instancedate="06/25/2018" type="hidden"><span>English II </span><br></div>
      </td>
      <td class="schedule__cell">
        <div data-sessionid="173" data-instancedate="06/26/2018" class="schedule__cell--wrap"><input data-testid="46181" data-sessionid="173" data-instanceid="341" data-instancedate="06/26/2018" type="hidden"><span>Algebra I</span><br><input data-testid="46184" data-sessionid="173" data-instanceid="342" data-instancedate="06/26/2018" type="hidden"><span>Biology</span><br>
          <input
            data-testid="46185" data-sessionid="173" data-instanceid="343" data-instancedate="06/26/2018" type="hidden"><span>U.S. History</span><br></div>
      </td>
      <td class="schedule__cell">
        <div data-sessionid="173" data-instancedate="06/27/2018" class="schedule__cell--wrap"><input data-testid="46182" data-sessionid="173" data-instanceid="312" data-instancedate="06/27/2018" type="hidden"><span>English I</span><br><input data-testid="46183" data-sessionid="173" data-instanceid="313" data-instancedate="06/27/2018" type="hidden"><span>English II </span><br></div>
      </td>
      <td class="schedule__cell">
        <div data-sessionid="173" data-instancedate="06/28/2018" class="schedule__cell--wrap"><input data-testid="46181" data-sessionid="173" data-instanceid="344" data-instancedate="06/28/2018" type="hidden"><span>Algebra I</span><br><input data-testid="46184" data-sessionid="173" data-instanceid="345" data-instancedate="06/28/2018" type="hidden"><span>Biology</span><br>
          <input
            data-testid="46185" data-sessionid="173" data-instanceid="346" data-instancedate="06/28/2018" type="hidden"><span>U.S. History</span><br></div>
      </td>
      <td class="schedule__cell">
        <div data-sessionid="173" data-instancedate="06/29/2018" class="schedule__cell--wrap"><svg data-instancedate="06/29/2018" class="schedule__cell--icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path fill="currentColor" d="M16 32C7.163 32 0 24.837 0 16S7.163 0 16 0s16 7.163 16 16-7.163 16-16 16zm2-18V8a2 2 0 1 0-4 0v6H8a2 2 0 1 0 0 4h6v6a2 2 0 1 0 4 0v-6h6a2 2 0 1 0 0-4h-6z"></path></svg></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```